# matplotlib equivalent for MATLABs truesize()

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and python and would like to display an image so that 1 pixel of the image is actually represented by 1 pixel in the figure. In MATLAB, this is achieved with the command `truesize()`. How can I do this in Python?

I tried playing around with the `imshow()` arguments as well as `set_dpi()` and `set_figwidth()/set_figheight()`, but with no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create images right down to the pixel level, why not [use PIL](http://jehiah.cz/archive/creating-images-with-numpy) in the first place? That way you wouldn't have to programatically calculate your true drawing area by substracting margins, labels and axis widths from the figure extend.

Answer (score 0):

This hack does what I wanted to do, though it's still not perfect:

```
h = mplt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest')

dpi = h.figure.get_dpi()
h.figure.set_figwidth(img.shape[0] / dpi)
h.figure.set_figheight(img.shape[1] / dpi)
h.figure.canvas.resize(img.shape[1] + 1, img.shape[0] + 1)

h.axes.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
h.axes.set_xlim(-1, img.shape[1])
h.axes.set_ylim(img.shape[0], -1)
```

It can be generalized to account for a margin around the axes holding the image.