# render image 1:1 on screen in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` and want to accomplish the equivalent of Matlab's `truesize`:

- resize an image so that 1 pixel renders as 1 pixel on screen
- resize the axes and figure **around** that transformed image so that the previous proportional relationships between figure, axes and image still hold.

This is not a duplicate of [matplotlib equivalent for MATLABs truesize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645049/matplotlib-equivalent-for-matlabs-truesize) —that and every other result I've googled takes the opposite approach to what I want: first setting up the figure to specified pixel dimensions, then making the axes fill the figure exactly (which I don't necessarily want).

I definitely want to use `matplotlib` (I want to use its tools to superimpose other figure elements on the image) rather than, say, `PIL`.

It seems like the kind of thing that is likely to exist somewhere under a name I haven't found yet.  My attempts to do this from scratch have come up against the apparent impossibility of resizing an existing figure window (is this true?)

Oh look, a tumbleweed.